# Unexpected behavior in pandas rolling correlation using offset

Tags: python, pandas

This is input pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':(1,2), 'y':(2,3)},
                  index=[pd.Timestamp('20180101'), pd.Timestamp('20180102')])
```

Why would these two return different results?

```
df.rolling(window='1d').corr()
df.rolling(window=1).corr()
```

Whether window is int or offset shouldn't matter, as in both cases size of the moving window is 1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you dive into the Pandas code and follow it to window.py, you'll get to :

```
    def _get_corr(a, b):

        a = a.rolling(window=window, min_periods=self.min_periods,
                      freq=self.freq, center=self.center)
        b = b.rolling(window=window, min_periods=self.min_periods,
                      freq=self.freq, center=self.center)

        return a.cov(b, **kwargs) / (a.std(**kwargs) * b.std(**kwargs))
```

If you print out the values for window and min_periods in your example

```
df.rolling(window='1d').corr()
```

has window=86400000000000 and min_periods=1, while

```
df.rolling(window=1).corr()
```

has window=1 and min_periods=None.

Your index is dtype='datetime64[ns]'

So, it looks like '1d' gets translated into 24*60*60*1000000000 or the number of nanoseconds per day.  So this is the same as '1d'.

```
df.rolling(window=86400000000000, min_periods=1).corr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Summary of [troy-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6410450/troy-d) Answer:

- `window='1d'` means window of 1 day
- `window=1` means window of 1 element